# Passing command line argument to SCons test

Tags: scons

I have a test, call it `sometest`, registered in SCons which can be invoked by doing:

```
scons sometest.test
```

But `sometest` also expects command-line arguments, namely it looks for the flag `-beHappy`, to run in another mode.

When I attempt to invoke the test using:

```
scons sometest.test -beHappy
```

I get a few warnings from SCons:

```
Warning:  ignoring -e option
Warning:  the -W option is not yet implemented
```

Then it proceeds to run the test without passing the parameter.

I tried

```
scons sometest.test -beHappy
scons 'sometest.test -beHappy'
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use scons, but it may be worth trying the old double hyphen, --. Many shells use this to disable option processing passing the options onto the underlying script to process.

`scons sometest.test -- -beHappy`

From bash's man page:

> > A -- signals the end of options and disables further option processing.  > Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames and arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.

Check out bash's *man* page and search for `--` for more information. If you use another shell be sure to check out that shell's man page as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
scons sometest.test --beHappy
```

SCons options that are longer than one character are prefixed with two dashes (`-`).

It's helpful to know that Scons uses [optparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html) under the hood.

When you entered `-beHappy`, scons read that as the equivalent `-b -e -H -a -p -p -y`